# How can I clear a vector layer before drawstart in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a vector layer in OL3 which I want to auto clear when drawing a **Point** feature (which means there is always max 1 feature in the layer).

Problem is that when I listen to drawstart (ol.interaction.draw) or to featureadd (ol.layer.vector) they are fired after feature is added and thus I can't clear the layer without them be deleted.

how can I workaround this ?

*** Edit ***
I've noticed the drawstart event work when the draw type isn't Point , but I want to add points and thus my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Points are a bit tricky because the `drawstart` and `drawend` events are driven from the same mouse click.  To support all geometry types, have a look at the sample code below.

If you only ever need to support the `ol.geom.Point` type, then just use the `drawend` event and don't worry about the rest.

**Sample Code**

```
var geomType, lastFeature;

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    wrapX: false
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: geomType
});

// removes the last feature from the vector source.
var removeLastFeature = function() {
    if (lastFeature)
      source.removeFeature(lastFeature);
};

// On draw start for polygon, line and circle types we need to 
// remove the previous feature so that it doesn't show.
draw.on('drawstart', function (e) {

    // Filter on all BUT points
    if (geomType !== 'Point')) {
       source.clear();  // implicit remove of last feature.
    }

});

// When a drawing ends for a point feature, remove the last feature
draw.on('drawend', function (e) {

    // Filter on points ONLY
    if (geomType === 'Point') {
        removeLastFeature();
    }
    lastFeature = e.feature;

});

map.addInteraction(draw);
```

**jsFiddle**

See a complete example here that handles all geometry types: 
https://jsfiddle.net/abb54n79/1/

Comment: Hi , I just figured that when type is Point (which is what I want to add) than the solution isn't working. it works only for LineString , Circle , Polygon.... Any idea how to apply same solution to point ?

Comment: I didn't consider points in the previous example.  My answer has been updated to support all geometry types.

Comment: That solution is excellent , may I ask you something on email ? (your site url don't have contact us)

Comment: Updated the code again, apparently the event feature isn't always the same geometry type as the drawing feature.  Especially the case for circles where the initial draw is a point.  Check my site again - there is a contact form, but was disabled.

Comment: Th , that solved the problem , And I've emailed you :)